# Adding Flex capabilities to an existing J2EE Enterprise Application Project

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, jakarta-ee

I have an J2EE Enterprise Application Project in which I would like to add a few Flex screens. How do I go about adding Flex capabilities.

I have build Flex/J2EE applications from scratch but can't think of the best way to do this.

I am currently using Flex Builder Plugin for IBM Rational Application Developer 7.5. Any idea on how to proceed.

J D

Answer (score 0):

The FB4 plugin has the ability to add different flex natures to your java project..right click on the project folder from package explorer and you should see an option Add/Change project type.

On the other hand, why would you want to use only one project both for Flex and Java? I found that is easier to work separately with them, especially if the project is large.

Comment: Thanks I see that option. What is the consideration in using "Flex Library Project Nature" vs "Flex Project Nature". 

As far creating separate projects, i wouldn't mind doing that as long as the projects reside inside my ear. So is there a way to create the Flex projects as a module to the ear.